# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier - Nonsensical error in React Enzyme testing

Tags: react-native, enzyme

I'm developing in React Native and trying to set up jest testing by following the directions at https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/react-native.html.

I think I've set everything up correctly. Here's my config:

```js
//setup-tests.js

import "react-native";
import "jest-enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import Enzyme from "enzyme";

 // Set up DOM in node.js environment for Enzyme to mount to
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");

const jsdom = new JSDOM("<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>");
const { window } = jsdom;

function copyProps(src, target) {
  Object.defineProperties(target, {
    ...Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(src),
    ...Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(target)
  });
}

global.window = window;
global.document = window.document;
global.navigator = {
  userAgent: "node.js"
};
copyProps(window, global);

// Set up Enzyme to mount to DOM, simulate events, and inspect the DOM in tests.
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

/* Ignore some expected warnings
 * see: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react.html#snapshot-testing-with-mocks-enzyme-and-react-16
 * see https://github.com/Root-App/react-native-mock-render/issues/6
 */
const originalConsoleError = console.error;
console.error = message => {
  if (message.startsWith("Warning:")) {
    return;
  }

  originalConsoleError(message);
};

// jest.config.js

module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: "<rootDir>setup-tests.js"
};

// Test.test.js

import React from "react";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import { mount, ReactWrapper } from "enzyme";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { Text } from "react-native";

import LoginView from '../js/LoginView'
```

You'll see the top of `LoginView` in a moment.

You'll notice that I haven't even written any tests in the test file, I'm just trying to get jest running to the point where it can evaluate a test.

Without the `import LoginView`, jest runs and "fails" because my test suite must contain at least one test. Sounds good.

Adding in the `import LoginView`, I get this error (which shows the import statements at the top of `LoginView`:

```
    import Button from './buttons/Button';
           ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

      1 | import React, { Component } from "react";
    > 2 | import { Input, Button, Image } from "react-native-elements";
        | ^
      3 | import { Text, View } from "react-native";
      4 | import { connect } from "react-redux";
      5 | import F8StyleSheet from "./F8StyleSheet";

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:471:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:513:25)
      at Object.<anonymous> (js/LoginView.js:2:1)
```

So this doesn't make sense to me for a number of reasons.

1. `LoginView` renders fine in the actual app, with no "Unexpected identifier" crashes or warnings or anything
2. The lower arrows in the error on line 2 point to `import`, which of course shouldn't be unexpected.
3. Then there's the upper arrows that indicate a line from `react-native-elements`, so, I don't know about that.

Now, it does occur to me that the `jest.config.js` file did require me to use `module.exports`, and fails/crashes when I tried using `export default { setupFiles }` (or however I tried to do it, allowing VS Code to update it to ES6 syntax). So maybe that's why it's not liking `import`.

Even if that's the case, I don't know what the heck to do next.

### Update

I put in the code suggested in Brian's answer, and I'm now getting all new errors. Even though the errors suggest fixes, it doesn't seem to help –- I've added the following to my `package.json` under `jest`. I'm not sure where `Dimensions.js` is anyway; plus, I would assume that all this setup I'm doing for React Native in particular would know how to identify the convention of having `file.ios.js` and `file.android.js` be equivalent to `file`.

Here's my "fix" following the instructions, which doesn't help at all.

```
 "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "jsx",
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "node",
      "ios.js",
      "android.js"
    ]
```

And here's the new errors.

```
 FAIL  tests/Test.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module './Platform' from 'Dimensions.js'

    However, Jest was able to find:
        './Platform.android.js'
        './Platform.ios.js'

    You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'node'].

    See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string

    However, Jest was able to find:
        '../Utilities/Dimensions.js'

    You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'node'].

    See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string

    However, Jest was able to find:
        'buttons/Button.js'

    You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'node'].

    See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string

    However, Jest was able to find:
        '../js/LoginView.js'

    You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'node'].

    See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:229:17)
      at Object.require (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/Dimensions.js:14:18)
```

Comment: I am having a similar issue, reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55807239/react-ga-redux-v7-incompatibility-issue-with-jest), did you managed to solve you issue or are you still stuck ?
It could be a compatibility issue with some other packages...

Answer (score 2):

`react-native-elements` contains ES6 code.

ES6 code needs to be compiled before it can be run by `Jest`.

By default `Jest` doesn't compile anything in `node_modules`, but `react-native` has a `jest-preset` that [tells `Jest` to compile `react-native` and `@react-native-community` modules](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/65d6c3f3a0908699ce8782625d09ca9cd12edd45/jest-preset.js#L31-L33).

To include `react-native-elements` you will need to tell `Jest` to compile it as well by [adding the following to your `Jest` config](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react-native#transformignorepatterns-customization):

```
transformIgnorePatterns: [
  'node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|@react-native-community|react-native-elements)',
]
```