# React-GA + Redux v7 incompatibility issue with jest

Tags: reactjs, redux, google-analytics, react-redux, react-ga

I am using `react-ga` v2.5.7, for which I updated `react-redux` v7.0.2, and I am using `jest` v24.7.1

I set `react-ga` in `testMode`, and it is mocked in my `jest.setup.js`. But everytime I run my tests I am always encountering the same issue, most of the tests are failing for some weird reason:

```
Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@icons/material/CheckIcon' from 'SwatchesColor.js'

    However, Jest was able to find:
        './SwatchesColor.js'

    You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'node'].

    See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string

    However, Jest was able to find:
        './SwatchesGroup.js'

    You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'node'].

    See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string

    However, Jest was able to find:
        'components/swatches/Swatches.js'

    You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'node'].

    See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string

    However, Jest was able to find:
        './VisualIdentityColorPicker.js'
        './VisualIdentityColorPicker.spec.js'

    You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'node'].

    See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string

    However, Jest was able to find:
        './VisualIdentityBackgroundSelector.js'
        './VisualIdentityBackgroundSelector.spec.js'

    You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'node'].

    See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string
```

Though SwatchesColors is a dependency of a module completely unrelated. 
I seems to me that there is an incompatibility issues and the only things that have changed in my project are the addition of `react-ga` and the update of `react-redux`, as anyone encounter a similar issue ?
How did you solved it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the actual issue, it seem to be related to a component not import that was causing a strange behaviour in the tests.

Once I imported it, the issues disappeared.